# Question about complement of borel set

Tags: measure-theory, borel-sets

Let $A⊆\mathbb{R}$
be the set $A=\{x\in(0,1)$:
the decimal expansion of x
contains infinitely many 7's}.

$A^c⊆\mathbb{R}$
be the set $A=\{x\in(0,1)$:
the decimal expansion of x
contains finitely many 7's}.

$A$ is borel set , is it correct that $A^c$ is borel set as well ?

I denote $A_n := \{x\in(0,1)\mid \text{the $n$th digit of the decimal expression of $x$ is 7}\}.$

$A_n := \{x\in(0,1)\mid \text{the $n$th digit of the decimal expression of $x$ is 7}\}.$

$A'_n:= \{x\in(0,1)\mid \text{the $n$th digit of the decimal expression of $x$ is 7 where the 7's digits is finite }\}.$

I consider $A'_n\subset A_n$.

Since $A_n$ is Borel as it is a finite union of half-intervals and $A'_n\subset A_n$ implies $A'_n$ is Borel.

Is it correct ?

In general ,Any subset of Borel set is Borel ?
any complement of borel set is Borel ?

Appreciaite any help.

Comment: A complement of a Borel set is Borel because the Borel sets are defined to be a sigma algebra

Comment: But subsets of Borel sets need not be Borel sets - e.g. every set of reals is a subset of the Borel set $\mathbb{R}$, but not every set of reals is Borel.

Comment: *Any subset of Borel set is Borel ?* -- If this were true, then because $\mathbb R$ is a Borel set in the reals (in fact, it's both an open and a closed subset in the reals), it would follow that EVERY subset of $\mathbb R$ is a Borel set (in the reals), which hopefully you know is not true.